# get some values from string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string like

```
ips_string="private_ips = {\n  \"Spoke1-VM\" = \"10.61.73.2\"\n  \"Spoke2-VM\" = \"10.62.76.17\"\n}\npublic_ips = {\n  \"Spoke1-VM\" = \"52.58.132.6\"\n  \"Spoke2-VM\" = \"52.59.211.17\"\n}"
```

And I want to get output in a array something like this

```
["10.61.73.2" , "10.62.76.17", '52.58.132.6','52.59.211.17']
```

I tried regex etc but not having any fruitful output

Comment: Please read site rules carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex with a pattern that basically looks for 4 digits, joined by decimals.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', ips_string)
['10.61.73.2', '10.62.76.17', '52.58.132.6', '52.59.211.17']
```

Comment: thanks for answer ,  But how it working . can you please include few words of explanation ?

Comment: @pie, here's some info for you about re and findall.   [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If there are more than one item, you will get a list.  In this example, you have \d+ which looks for one or more digits. The pattern r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' says, look for digits dot digits dot... (as per the ip format). For each find, it pulls it and adds to a list. That list is finally available to you.

Comment: See [example here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-regex-re-search-vs-re-findall/)

Comment: r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' will look for digits in ip format (digits dot digits dot ....). Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax and it has description about the use of d (digits)

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
ips_string="private_ips = {\n  \"Spoke1-VM\" = \"10.61.73.2\"\n  \"Spoke2-VM\" = \"10.62.76.17\"\n}\npublic_ips = {\n  \"Spoke1-VM\" = \"52.58.132.6\"\n  \"Spoke2-VM\" = \"52.59.211.17\"\n}"
pat = re.compile('(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}')
matches = re.findall(pat, ips_string)
print(matches)  # -> ['10.61.73.2', '10.62.76.17', '52.58.132.6', '52.59.211.17']
```